# Bitbucket Heads issue

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I push up to bitbucket using Sourcetree app I get the following code placed into my files. Is there a way I can stop this from happening, My merges are fine when I commit my changes.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

>>>>>>> de31d33546973a5ebe11787596ffbb4a8000d6fe
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those mean you have conflicts in your files and you should resolve them. Go through all files having that and compare between code under `HEAD` and code under `de31d33546973a5ebe11787596ffbb4a8000d6fe`, then keep only what you need.

> ```
> <<<<<<< HEAD
> ```
>
> code of  HEAD
>
> ```
> >>>>>>> de31d33546973a5ebe11787596ffbb4a8000d6fe
> ```
>
> code of  de31d33546973a5ebe11787596ffbb4a8000d6fe

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

When I face the same problem. the best way to get rid of is to **reset all changes,** and to push the last commit to repository. Or you have to solve all the conflicts in the files before pushing them to repository.